# How to download a file from RStudio server using a function?

Tags: r, file, download, rstudio

I'm trying to download a local file I have on RStudio hosted on a server, but programmatically with a script/function (instead of clicking Files > Check on file > More > Export in the UI).

I've tried with `download.file()` but it requires an `url` (instead of the local file) and `destfile` instead of simply downloading it in my browser as any file downloads.

Is it even possible to achieve with a function I don't know of? Maybe with `system()` somehow? Ideally if it's resilient to any tool running R, say Jupyter notebooks. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but you can try `rstudioapi::executeCommand` with [one of these commands](https://docs.posit.co/ide/server-pro/2022.06.0-daily+2.pro2/rstudio_ide_commands/rstudio_ide_commands.html), perhaps exportFiles

Comment: `download.file` can also handle `file://` links to local files as per `?download.file` - "*The 'url' must start with a scheme such as 'http://', 'https://', 'ftp://' or 'file://'.*" Also see the `file.*` functions like `file.copy`

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, that makes sense, but what about the `destfile` parameter? 
Thanks @RicVillalba but that solution is not quite scalable, given I also have to manually check which files to export because I can't seem to pass arguments. Also, it'd only work for RStudio and not other platforms.

Comment: @Bernardo - you have to download the file to *somewhere*, which is what `destfile=` is asking for. Even if you download a file through a browser, it still gets saved somewhere (by default possibly in c:\windows\temp or /tmp) to then be opened.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, I get it must be downloaded somewhere but I can't seem to find the way of it working given it doesn't understand I'm not trying to download into a server's directory but a local one (I'm in macOS). Tried several variances of /Users/myuser/Desktop but none worked. That's the real challenge here.

Comment: @Bernardo - by default if you just specify the filename - `destfile="blah.txt"` it will go into your working directory that you can see the full path of via `getwd()` and set with `setwd("path/to/directory")` - otherwise you have to specify the path in full - `"/Users/myuser/Desktop/blah.txt"` - it's the dest*file* not the dest*directory*

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for your help here. Yes, I know. The thing is that I don't want to export the file into my server's working directory, but to my local computer, same result as manually exporting the file with "Files > (Check on file) > More > Export" but with a function. `"/Users/myuser/Desktop/blah.txt"` can't be used because it doesn't exist in my server, but in my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For some files, it's very simple:
use: `rstudioapi::viewer("path/to/file.tsv")`

Be warned though, that this might clock the rstudioserver if you use it for large files. Many files (.html, .png, .pdf) are however directly displayed by the browser instead of downloaded (if you need them downloaded consider renaming them first)

---

As @ric pointed out in their comment, you can export the file(s) currently selected in the files pane using: `rstudioapi::executeCommand("exportFiles")`
You can also automatically navigate to your file of interest using
`rstudioapi::filesPaneNavigate("<path to file (relative to current working directory)>")` but I could not figure out a way to automatically *select* a file in the files pane,
presumably because the selection state is not managed on the server but in the browser. So you could in theory write some javascript that reacts on some dom changes induced by any rstudioapi calls to select your file of interested.

I just needed the same file over and over again (after modifications) and thus got away with select it manually once...

To solve your underlying problem, consider a strategy that does not send the file through your browser. E.g. `system("rsync yourfile yoursshserver:~/")` or `googledrive::drive_upload("yourfile", "folder_in_your_gdrive/yourfile")`.